# php looks for openssl in wrong directory

Tags: php

I have just downloaded php 7, I am on windows, I changed my environment path to where php is -> c:\php7.3.4

I enable openssl in the php.ini by uncommenting it, then i run php in bash I get an error that suggests its looking in the wrong folder

here is the error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'
>   (tried: C:\p hp\ext\openssl (The specified module could not be
>   found.), C:\php\ext\php_openss l.dll (The specified module could not
>   be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Im not sure how to proceed to be honest, its looking in c:php instead of c:\php7.3.4

Comment: It gets the path from your php.ini file. The location of the php.ini file is set at compile time.

Comment: in bash? but this looks like a windows' path.

Comment: @symcbean thanks ill look in php.ini see if i can find the line

Comment: @shingo I install git for windows which comes with a bash shell